# In a Django serializer, how to set foreign key field based on view argument?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Using the Django REST Framework, I would like to allow users to create and save instances of a Django model through a `ListCreateAPIView` (via `POST`). One of the fields (a foreign-key field called `domain`) shall be determined from a view parameter as defined in `urls.py`.

Furthermore, the user can modify the model instance later using `PUT` or `PATCH` requests to a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` endpoint (using the same serializer). I don't want the user to be able to modify the `domain` field at this point.

While I have the code for the model and the view / serializer structure ready, I'm not sure how to tell the serializer to determine the value of the `domain` field based on the view parameter. Here's what I got:

```
class RRset(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rrsets')
    subname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

... and a straight-forward `ListCreateAPIView`:

```
class RRsetsDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RRsetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.kwargs['name']
        return RRset.objects.filter(domain__name=name, domain__owner=self.request.user.pk)
```

`urls.py` contains the following line:

```
url(r'^domains/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z\.\-_0-9]+)/rrsets/$', RRsetsDetail.as_view(), name='rrsets')
```

This allows the user to list and create `RRset` objects using the `RRsetsSerializer` serializer (the `name` field is listed for completeness only, but I do not believe it to be important in this context):

```
class RRsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return '.'.join(filter(None, [obj.subname, obj.domain.name])) + '.' # returns 'subname.name.'

    class Meta:
        model = RRset
        fields = ('created', 'updated', 'domain', 'name', 'type',)
        read_only_fields = ('created', 'updated', 'domain', 'type',)
```

Questions:

1. What do I need to modify to have the serializer take the `domain` name from the view `name` parameter?
2. The the serializer's `read_only_fields` setting prevents the user from modifying the `domain` field later. However, I'm not sure if this setting somehow interacts with the serializer trying to set a default value (can the serializer write the default value, even if read-only is set)?

To summarize: What I'm looking for is something like a "write-once field with a default value based on a view parameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [HiddenField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield) with a combination of [CreateOnlyDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault)

> **HiddenField**
>
> A field class that does not take a value based on user input, but instead takes its value from a default value or callable.
>
> **CreateOnlyDefault**
>
> A default class that can be used to only set a default argument during
>   create operations. During updates the field is omitted.
>
> It takes a single argument, which is the default value or callable
>   that should be used during create operations.

And because you want to access the view, you can't just use callable, but you have to use [Class-based](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#class-based) callable which can have access to a context data.

```
class DomainDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        view = serializer_field.context['view']
        request = serializer_field.context['request']
        self.domain = ...#determine the domain based on request+view

    def __call__(self):
        return self.domain


class RRsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    domain = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(DomainDefault()))
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising. However, I'm getting the following error (|| by me, denoting newline):
Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 257, in set_context || self.default.set_context(serializer_field) || TypeError: set_context() missing 1 required positional argument: 'serializer_field'
I was unable to figure out what's wrong. Do you know?

Comment: Instantiate the `DomainDefault` class, i.e. use `DomainDefault()` instead of just `DomainDefault`. Gonna update the answer.